# setup.py in build wheel dlib in ubuntu goes on forever

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to install face_recognition module with pip3 in python3 (version 3.5). I have already installed all the pre-required modules including cmake, libboost etc. However whenever I try to install face_recognition with the following command -

```
    sudo -H pip3 install face_recognition
```

The terminal gets stuck at line setup.py in build wheel dlib which seems to go on forever only after long time displays some error regarding c++ and cmake failed.

```
smartdb@ubuntu:~$ sudo -H pip3 install face_recognition
[sudo] password for smartdb: 
Collecting face_recognition
  Downloading face_recognition-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from face_recognition)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from face_recognition)
Collecting Click>=6.0 (from face_recognition)
  Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 71kB 400kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from face_recognition)
Collecting face-recognition-models>=0.2.0 (from face_recognition)
  Downloading face_recognition_models-0.3.0.tar.gz (100.1MB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 100.2MB 2.8kB/s 
Collecting dlib>=19.5 (from face_recognition)
  Using cached dlib-19.8.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: face-recognition-models, dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for face-recognition-models ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/05/32/f2/440351db9ce1eb483696f83300f3d313f2f265403f0e69c481
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qdefttr5/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp57qgi2e_pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Detected Python architecture: 64bit
  Detected platform: linux
  Configuring cmake ...
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1534 (message):
    No header defined for python-py34; skipping header check
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /tmp/pip-build-qdefttr5/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:66 (FIND_PACKAGE)
    CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
  -- Could NOT find Boost
  CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1534 (message):
    No header defined for python-py35; skipping header check
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /tmp/pip-build-qdefttr5/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:68 (FIND_PACKAGE)
    CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
  -- Boost version: 1.62.0
  -- Found the following Boost libraries:
  --   python-py35
  -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (found suitable version "3.5.3", minimum required is "3.4")
  -- Enabling SSE4 instructions
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Looking for pthread_create
  -- Looking for pthread_create - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
  -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
  -- Looking for gethostbyname
  -- Looking for gethostbyname - found
  -- Looking for connect
  -- Looking for connect - found
  -- Looking for remove
  -- Looking for remove - found
  -- Looking for shmat
  -- Looking for shmat - found
  -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
  -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
  -- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
  -- Looking for png_create_read_struct
  -- Looking for png_create_read_struct - found
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
  -- Checking for module 'cblas'
  --   No package 'cblas' found
  -- Checking for module 'lapack'
  --   No package 'lapack' found
  -- Looking for sys/types.h
  -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
  -- Looking for stdint.h
  -- Looking for stdint.h - found
  -- Looking for stddef.h
  -- Looking for stddef.h - found
  -- Check size of void*
  -- Check size of void* - done
  -- A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
  -- LAPACK requires BLAS
   *****************************************************************************
   *** No BLAS library found so using dlib's built in BLAS.  However, if you ***
   *** install an optimized BLAS such as OpenBLAS or the Intel MKL your code ***
   *** will run faster.  On Ubuntu you can install OpenBLAS by executing:    ***
   ***    sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev                 ***
   *** Or you can easily install OpenBLAS from source by downloading the     ***
   *** source tar file from http://www.openblas.net, extracting it, and      ***
   *** running:                                                              ***
   ***    make; sudo make install                                            ***
   *****************************************************************************
  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
  -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
  -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
  -- C++11 activated.
  -- USING BOOST_LIBS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.so
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.5 (found version "3.5.3")
  -- Found Python with installed numpy package
  -- Numpy include path '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-build-qdefttr5/dlib/tools/python/build
  Build using cmake ...
  Scanning dependencies of target dlib
  [  0%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
  [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
  [ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
  [ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
  [ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
  [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
  [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
  [ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 21%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
  [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
  [ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
  [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
  [ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
  [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
  [ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
  [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
  [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
  [ 32%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
  [ 34%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
  [ 35%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/tensor_tools.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
  [ 36%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/widgets.cpp.o
  [ 37%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/drawable.cpp.o
  [ 38%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp.o
  [ 39%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/style.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp.o
  [ 40%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp.o
  [ 41%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.cpp.o
  [ 42%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
  [ 43%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
  [ 44%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcomapi.cpp.o
  [ 45%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapimin.cpp.o
  [ 45%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapistd.cpp.o
  [ 46%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatasrc.cpp.o
  [ 47%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcoefct.cpp.o
  [ 48%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcolor.cpp.o
  [ 49%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jddctmgr.cpp.o
  [ 50%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdhuff.cpp.o
  [ 50%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdinput.cpp.o
  [ 51%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmainct.cpp.o
  [ 52%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmarker.cpp.o
  [ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmaster.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmerge.cpp.o
  [ 54%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdphuff.cpp.o
  [ 55%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdpostct.cpp.o
  [ 56%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdsample.cpp.o
  [ 57%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jerror.cpp.o
  [ 58%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctflt.cpp.o
  [ 59%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctfst.cpp.o
  [ 59%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctint.cpp.o
  [ 60%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctred.cpp.o
  [ 61%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemmgr.cpp.o
  [ 62%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemnobs.cpp.o
  [ 63%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant1.cpp.o
  [ 63%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant2.cpp.o
  [ 64%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jutils.cpp.o
  [ 65%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapimin.cpp.o
  [ 66%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatadst.cpp.o
  [ 67%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcparam.cpp.o
  [ 68%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapistd.cpp.o
  [ 68%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmarker.cpp.o
  [ 69%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcinit.cpp.o
  [ 70%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmaster.cpp.o
  [ 71%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcdctmgr.cpp.o
  [ 72%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccoefct.cpp.o
  [ 72%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccolor.cpp.o
  [ 73%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jchuff.cpp.o
  [ 74%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmainct.cpp.o
  [ 75%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcphuff.cpp.o
  [ 76%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcprepct.cpp.o
  [ 77%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcsample.cpp.o
  [ 77%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctint.cpp.o
  [ 78%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctflt.cpp.o
  [ 79%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctfst.cpp.o
  [ 80%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
  [ 81%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
  [ 81%] Linking CXX static library libdlib.a
  [ 81%] Built target dlib
  Scanning dependencies of target dlib_
  [ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
  [ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
  [ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
  [ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
  [ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/svm_rank_trainer.cpp.o
  [ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/decision_functions.cpp.o
  [ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/other.cpp.o
  [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/basic.cpp.o
  [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/cca.cpp.o
  [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.o
  c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.o] Error 4
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all' failed
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
  Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  error: cmake build failed!

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware Workstation 14 Pro

Comment: What version of ubuntu and what kind of computer?

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the output?

> ```
> c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
> Please submit a full bug report,
> with preprocessed source if appropriate.
> See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs>
> ```

Your compiler crashed. That should not happen. Please update your compiler (GCC 7 or newest 6.x release) or switch to Clang from the LLVM project.
If it keeps crashing with newer versions of GCC, please file the bug.

Beside that, there is nothing you can do.